# How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to read SMS messages from Inbox,Draft,and sent from my blackberry device programmatically.

Would any one will help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only way to access SMS messages, implement MessageListener and intercept messages when they are sending/receiving. There is no API to access SMS messages already saved in device memory (i.e already received).

Answer (score 0):

See the BlackBerry Developers Knowledge Base article:
[What is - Different ways to listen for SMS messages](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_listen_for_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1357551&vernum=0)