# read all SMS from Inbox at a time in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sms, inbox

I am working on a sms application, in which i have used folder listener to access the Inbox sms.
I want to read all the sms present in the inbox at a time. Is it possible to do this, because what i have done is to read incoming sms.
When a sms added in the Inbox folder we can catch that event but here I want ot read all the sms from Inbox.

Please suggest me the solution or some fruity sample code.
Thanxsss a ton in advance...!

Comment: more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551210/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-blackberry

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read already received sms-messages. The only way is to implement MessageListener and intercept incoming sms-messages to process them.

Comment: Oh, its really big blockage in my way, I was looking for a way to move ahead. Please suggest!

Comment: Unfortunately RIM API does not provide a way to access already saved sms-messages. The only possible way is implementing MessageListener and intercept sms-messages when they are receiving and/or sending.

Comment: Thanx alot for ur guidance, I am working on a sms application, to store all the msgs of inbox on Server, for that I need to read those all msgs of the inbox. Now it will be tough to read messages when they received or sent and call web-service and send them on server.