# Blackberry - Read SMS and MMS from inbox

Tags: blackberry, listener, port, mms, interception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I read SMS messages from the inbox programmatically in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551210/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-blackberry)

I am trying to intercept/read incoming sms and mms for my project. I am able to successfully intercept sms, by listening to "sms://:3590". However I am not able to intercept mms. I have tried various ports, but always failed.

I went through the mmsdemo app available, and also used their method of listening for incoming mms, but was not able to.

Could anyone tell me the right way to listen for incoming mms on blackberry?

Else, is there a way I can root the blackberry and access the file system for the existing mms in the phone memory?

Comment: if you want to listen sms's , then check this link http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_listen_for_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1357551&vernum=0

Comment: I am able to listen to sms's. Intercepting mms's is the PROBLEM. any advice?